# What does "$#" mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script with this:

```
login {
    # checking parameters -> if not ok print error and exit script
    if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ $1 == '' ] || [ $2 == '' ]; then
        echo "Please check the needed options (username and password)"
        echo ""
        echo "For further Information see Section 13"
        echo ""
        echo "Press any key to exit"
        read
        exit
    fi

  } # /login
```

But I really dont know what the `$#` means on the third line.

Comment: Number of parameters passed to the script.

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times over.

Comment: @devnull Makes sense since this function is called like this: ```login $USER $PASS``` Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20272085/827263

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323847/what-do-and-stand-for-in-shell-script/

Comment: @devnull dupe, yes, but this question has the *far* superior title. Editing linked question now.

Comment: @kojiro Symbols and special characters cannot be searched anyways.  (And marking a question as duplicate doesn't _restrict_ anyone from posting answers anyways.)

Comment: @devnull I think it's very relevant for the human reading the summary, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pound sign counts things.

1. If it's just `$#`, it's the number of positional parameters, like `$1`, `$2`, `$3`. (Not counting `$0`, mind you.)
2. If it's `${#var}`, it's the number of characters in the expansion of the parameter. (String length)
3. If it's `${#var[@]}`, it's the number of elements in the array. Since bash arrays are sparse, this can be *different* from the index of the last element plus one.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of arguments passed.

You can read it [here](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0130.php), search for "Detecting command line arguments"